# Viewing pending changes that are set in the SPFILE

Tags: oracle

How do I see what pending changes have been made to an SPFILE before I bounce the database?  I know I can see changes in alert log, but it may have been a few months when the change had been made.

For example:

```
alter system set sga_max_size=1024M scope=spfile;
```

This doesn't become active until the next bounce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get some noise in the results from this for various reasons, but you can get close by:

```
select name, value from v$spparameter where isspecified = 'TRUE'
  minus
select name, value from v$parameter;
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of an official view that does this, but it ought to be feasible to read the spfile as an external table and join it to v$parameter.

Answer (score -1):

In 11g you can do:

CREATE PFILE='dir/init_current.ora' FROM MEMORY;

and

CREATE PFILE='dir/init_spfile.ora' FROM SPFILE;

and then just compare these text files (sort lines in both files first if necessary).